# variable array for LINEST

Tags: arrays, excel, variables

For a variable length array, how can the Line estimate variables be determined (the problem is the LINEST function requires a set range of values and I would like to vary the range).

Comment: if the size of the array changes due to inputs in Precedent cells, then the blank cells of a named array will cause the LINEST function to burp

Answer (score 0):

You can determine your set of values and put them in an array (just in case you can also not take into consideration some of 'em - for example the zeroes). You can write the array in a column/row if needed and `WorksheetFunction.Linest` the coefficients of a polynom in the same sheet. E.g. you want a cubic line estimation = you get a,b and c of the following formula: ax^3+bx^2+cx